# paint.setcolor not getting applied

Tags: java, android

I am using a custom edit text to display note activity in my app. The issue am currently facing is that i have been unable to change the underline paint color for the fields. The underline color seem to have a static one.
Tried so many solutions but don't seem to work to change the color.  What am i doing wrong?

```
public class LinedEditText extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText {
    private Rect mRect;
    private Paint mPaint;
    public LinedEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        mRect = new Rect();
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        int color = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
        mPaint.setColor(color);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        int height = canvas.getHeight();
        int curHeight = 0;
        Rect r = mRect;
        Paint paint = mPaint;
        int baseline = getLineBounds(0, r);
        for (curHeight = baseline + 1; curHeight < height;
             curHeight += getLineHeight())
        {
            canvas.drawLine(r.left, curHeight, r.right, curHeight, paint);
        }
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        invalidate();
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}


<com.app.example.notetaker.LinedEditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
    android:minLines="10"
    android:imeOptions="actionNone"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/note_et_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/note_et_title"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/note_et_title"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/note_et_title"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:hint="enter your note"
    android:gravity="top"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested you code and it is working fine, so i think that error in color resourse file. The string must be somethink like this for red color: `<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#f00</color>`
Also try to set color directly to code for checking like this:  `int color = 0xFF00CC00;` for example for green color.

Comment: Color.parseColor was what worked for me. Thanks for your effort buddy.